# How do I know when the iOS device is now connected to internet?

Tags: ios, ios8, network-programming, wifi

I have a question, I am developing an app for people who normally works in a zone that does not have an internet connection, the app will store data (coreData) during the day but when the device is connected to internet, the application must send the stored data to be saved in the cloud. Can I know when the device change from not connected to connected? Can I launch my app when that happen? Can my app wait for events in the background? Any clues? Anything like a service in Android?
I think about how WhatsApp works, I mean, when I am not connected, I do not receive any messages but when I am connected (even if the app is not running), automatically the app start and I receive all my messages.
Thank you and Hello from Bogotá!

Answer (score 1):

To check for an internet connection on an IOS device using swift, use this code below...

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0 {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

        return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? true : false
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am using Objective-C ¿Can I use the same? and ¿can I be notified when the state pass from not connected to connected in order to do some logic?